# Erlang tracer source code

Tags: erlang, trace

Does anybody know which Erlang source files are responsible for its tracer (the **trace** BIF).

I am looking into the possibility of synchronous tracing in Erlang (where the monitored process waits for go-ahead from the monitoring process receiving the trace messages). For now I'm trying to decide whether to try modifying Erlang's source code or generate a parser for this sort of thing. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to look at `erts/emulator/beam/erl_bif_trace.c` first, as that implements `trace/3` and friends. (`trace/3` is implemented by the C function `trace_3()`, for example.)

You may also be interested in `erl_trace.c`, which looks to be the functions that do a lot of the tracing work for the emulator.

Comment: beam_bp.c also does some work afair, mostly in modifying the code to generate traces

Comment: Thanks Warren and Lukas. I will look into the code you pointed out.